# How to change the default program used by Outlook 2010 for displaying the source of an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, html

I installed a demo version of a text editor recently (Ultraedit) and it appears to have set itself up as the default viewer for the html source of messages (via right-click -> View Source).

Now that I have uninstalled it, Outlook can't show the source of the messages so I need to associate my usual editor with this process. Does anyone know where this is configured?

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source
>   Editor\Editor Name

Comment: I don't have that key?

Comment: Then try to create this key and set the full path to notepad.exe as its default value.

Comment: Tried that! Still not working :-(